# Is there a way to see what permissions an ios app store app asks for, except manually opening it?

Tags: ios, security, permission

I am looking for a way to see what permissions an app asks for without opening it.
For Android you can view it in the store as seen below. Is is maybe possible to get the info.plist file for an app store app and see it there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the app is installed go to Settings -> AppName and the list of permissions will be there

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the existing answer.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke they are 26 seconds apart..reasonable I think. Plus OP reported that it doesn't work. Only "asked so far" permissions are listed

Comment: Oh, I missed that they were posted so soon after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings (scroll down) >  yourApp. It would list all the things it might ask later.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are only listed permissions that have already been asked for while using the app.

Comment: deleting then :p